# Getting the longest link in list of links in python

Tags: python

I have a list of edges as follows:

```
edges_1 = ['a::b::c', 'a::b', 'a', 'a::d','a::d::e', 'a::d::e::f']
edges_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I am trying to write a function which return the longest links.. which for above cases will return

```
['a::b::c','a::d::e::f']
```

and for second case

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

My thoughts is using networkx and build a graph and then traverse the longest sequence.. but i was wondering if there is another data structure or approach I am missing which would solve this case.

Comment: It's not clear why you'd expect `'a::b::c'` to return in the results of the first case

Comment: @alfasin: Good question.. Think of the edges as a graph.. So, we have to edges.. a->b->c and a->d->e->f.. everything else is in between.. what i want is these final full edges. .. rather than what i have now... a, a->b etc.. Does that makes sense?

Comment: I think is not clear yet, what do you mean by "everything else is in between" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your notes in the comments, I have modified the code.

This assumes that the graphs are DAGs and that the goal is to eliminate all sequences that are subsequences of others in the list.

Instead of looking at the length of each sequence, we can just discard any sequences that are subsets of other sequences. To do this, we can use the `str` subset operator.

```
print(f"Initial list: {edges_1}")
keepers = []

for edge in edges_1:
    other_edges = edges_1[:]
    other_edges.remove(edge)
    print(f"Test {edge} against {other_edges}")
    for rest in other_edges:
        if edge in rest:
            # Discard any edges that are subsets an an edge in `other_edges`
            print(f"Found match {edge} -> {rest}")
            break
    else:
        # If the edge hasn't been discarded, it is a "longest edge"
        keepers.append(edge)
        print(f"No greater matches found for {edge}")

print(f"The longest edges: {keepers}")
```

This code isn't the most efficient nor cleanest, but does highlight the basic mechanics of how to solve the problem.

**Old answer: solved w/o more description from OP**

If you can always assume an edge between vertices is denoted by '::', then you can use some simple string processing to obtain the length of each sequence.

This solution assumes that you always want the longest two sequences.

```
edges_1 = ['a::b::c', 'a::b', 'a', 'a::d','a::d::e', 'a::d::e::f']
edges_2 = ['a', 'b']

def print_longest_two_sequences(edges):
    links = [edge.split("::") for edge in edges]
    links.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
    links = ["::".join(edge) for edge in links]
    print(links[:2])

print_longest_two_sequences(edges_1)
print_longest_two_sequences(edges_2)
```

Comment: Thanks for response.. but this will not work if I have
edges_1 = ['a::b::c', 'a::b', 'a', 'a::d','a::d::e', 'a::d::e::f', 'a::d::e::g']
In this case it should return 'a::b::c', 'a::d::e::f' and 'a::d::e::g'
Also, 2 is not hardcoded.. for example edges_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

Comment: It sounds like your problem is not very well defined.  Why would you not expect it to return 'a::d::e'?  How can you tell which sequences it should return?  The longest? The longest few? All that are longer than a certain length?

Comment: Sorry the question was not clear..copying pasting from comment in question
Think of the edges as a graph.. So, we have to edges..` a->b->c` and `a->d->e->f `.. everything else is in between.. what i want is these final full edges. .. rather than what i have now... a, a->b etc.. Does that makes sense
So, 'a::d::e' is not returned because.. there is a bigger link `a->d->e->f` and `a->d->e->g`

Comment: Is your graph a DAG?, if not, how the longest sequence defined?, without repeteated nodes?

Comment: @bones.felipe: yepp

Answer (score 2):

I think this problem is related to the notion of an [upper set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_set).

Here's a solution that translates your structures into lists of sets of edges. Then, it looks to see whether each of the sets has another member of the list that is an upper set of itself.

```
def has_upset(down, set_list):
    return any(down.intersection(s) == down for s in set_list if s != down)

def filter_downsets(set_list):
    return filter(lambda d: not has_upset(d, set_list), set_list)
```

And here's the usage (including getting your structures into set-form).

```
edges_1 = ['a::b::c', 'a::b', 'a', 'a::d','a::d::e', 'a::d::e::f']
edges_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

edge_sets_1 = [set(e.split('::')) for e in edges_1]
print filter_downsets(edge_sets_1)
# [set(['a', 'c', 'b']), set(['a', 'e', 'd', 'f'])]

edge_sets_2 = [set(e.split('::')) for e in edges_2]
print filter_downsets(edge_sets_2)
# [set(['a']), set(['b']), set(['c'])]
```